# Looping hierarchies in membership, finding out user's permissions

Tags: sql, permissions, membership

I'm crazy of the problem below.
There are users and groups, and the groups can contain both users and other groups:
`CREATE TABLE GroupMembership (GroupMembershipID, GroupID, GroupTypeID, MemberID, MemberTypeID)`
Fields **GroupTypeID** and **MebmerTypeID** are need to provide types because i have various types of groups and members.
Let name me as Jim and I have a group "Jim's friends" which contains users Bob, Jane and also group "Jerry's friends". At the same time Jerry has group "Jerry's friends" containing Steve, Chloe an "Jim's group". As we can see now there is a loop reference between me and Jerry. Everyone says that loops in hierarchies is an error. What about my case? Is there way to avoid loop?

Now the second question.
I have a table Permission which describes subject's permissions to certain objects:
`CREATE TABLE Permission (PermissionID, SubjectID, SubjectTypeID, ObjectID, ObjectTypeID, PermissionTypeID, [Value])`
Every subject (user, group or something else) has explicit permission to a certain object.
At the end point, to find out the rights of a certain user for certain object, I must render all user's membership tree (via GroupMembership), than join it to Permission and determine the closest (in GroupMembership hierarchy) and the best permission.
Seems like it's a common way, isn't it?

So, in this scope I need to solve next tasks:
1) Find out user's permission to the certain object
2) Find out all objects which are permitted for certain user
3) Find out all users who has explicit permissions for a certain object
Seems like it's a common task, right?

At the first I wanted to create some universal view which represents a subject, an object and the actual permission for that object (remember hierarchy in GroupMembership!). It would let me easily query it or join other queries to it. I've been trying to make proper SELECT for many days but it was good for one task and very bad for another (there were full scans etc). The same situation if I make functions. Now i'm broken with it all :( I don't know  what it the good way to solve that tasks. The architecture and the tasks both look common but I can't find solutions for similar problems in the internet.
Could you please give links, advises or point to my errors?
Very thankful,
Jim.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this in SQL. A group in a group? There is no way to generate a query that can walk that. Do it outside SQL.

You may be able to make: Groups: can contain users (but not groups). Supergroup: Can contain groups, but not supergroups or users. That will be a lot easier to handle.

Also if you stick with your structure, don't put both users and groups in the same table. Make two tables: a table for the groups in a group, and a table for the users in a group.

A combo like you have is a nightmare for SQL.